# Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Output

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I proposed a question early on infection rate data in 6 different hospitals for two years (N=12). After speaking with several people I decided that a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (Mann-Whitney U, Wilcoxon rank-sum) test is the best bet. What I am concerned about is whether I can use rates and what exactly the output means (I've never had to run this test in SAS so I'm not even sure I'm putting it in correctly). Two questions arise:
1.) Will this test show that there is no difference/difference between the 2011 infection rate and the 2012 infection rate?
2.) I was told that the exact Wilcoxon test is the best with small sample sizes so in running this along with the test I get a One-sided p-value of .03, but a two-sided p-value of .06. Do I interpret this the same way as any other test? And is there a CI associated with this test or do you strictly report the p-value and leave it at that?

MORE INFO:
  Rate = number of infections/ total patient days
  I feel this can also be run as a paired test which would lead me to the difference between the sign and signed rank tests that appear when you run Proc Univariate in SAS.

Comment: I agree with your "MORE INFO" paragraph, if they are the same 6 hospital before and after, I'd suggest looking into [Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test), which is the non-parametric version of paired sample t-test.

Comment: So when doing this I need to use a variable that is equal to the rate difference between the two years correct?

Comment: Yes, compute the difference first and the use the code:"PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=mydata; VAR theDifferenceBetween2Yrs; RUN;"

Comment: And [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-using-spss-statistics.php) is some good resource about how to interpret. It's on SPSS, but the content should be generalizable.

Comment: I can't quite follow your situation, & I think it will be hard for anyone to interpret your output, since you don't provide it. Can you post your data (or a small, example dataset) & the specific output you want help w/?